# Treat files with .C extensions as C++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VS Code plugin for C/C++ to treat .C files as C++ code?
The icon in the explorer on the left correctly indicates that my files with .C extension are C++, but intellisense treats C++ constructs inside these files as errors. Renaming the file to .cpp avoids this problem. Is there a configuration setting that would let me specify that .C extension corresponds to C++ code?

Answer (score 3):

Make a file association for C extensions to map to C++ as follows:

1. Open settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and scroll down to Files:**Associations**.
2. Click [Add Item]
3. Type *.C for the key and cpp for Value
4. Click [OK]